# Connecting hokuyo range finder to mobilesim

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, rosaria, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to perform a simulation of a p3dx using a hokuyo range finder as sensor but I don't know how to initialize the hokuyo node with the simulator.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48317/connecting-hokuyo-range-finder-to-mobilesim/) by [cf.morales46](https://answers.ros.org/users/3592/cf.morales46/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

MobileSim provides an abstract interface to its simulated laser, and this is not represented in ROSARIA yet.  So at this point only features represented in ROSARIA can be used in MobileSim (robot position, velocity control, bumpers, sonar).

Instead, you could simulate using Gazebo or Stage in ROS, and then later switch to real hardware using ROSARIA for mobile robot control and the hokuyo node for the laser.

Let me know if any documentation is confusing on this point, or if anyone has any ideas for how best to represent simulated devices in ROSARIA.

Reed

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2012-11-14**:
Note, I replaced this answer with an actual answer, previously I was referring you to MobileRobots support for MobileSim support. However, I only figured out after posting that you seemed to be using it with ROSARIA in ROS. Sorry.